# Get value of EXTERNAL_STORAGE environment variable on handset from shell script on OS X

Tags: android, adb

I would like to be able to fetch the value of the `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` variable on my Android handset from an ant `build.xml` script running on OS X so that I can subsequently perform an `adb push` of a file to that location on the handset.

When I am shelled into the handset, I can see the value just fine:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
/mnt/sdcard
```

When I try to get that value back on OS X using a one-line `adb shell` command, I get nothing:

```
$ adb shell "echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `$`. Like this:

```
adb shell "echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Otherwise shell variable expansion happens locally before the command gets sent to the device and your command ends up being `adb shell "echo "` since the local `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not set.